# Ansible create files with user permissions in homedir of existing users

Tags: ansible-playbook

I have homedir of few users like that
/home/user1
/home/user2
/home/user(n-1)

I need ansible to get list of homedir and create file inside every homedir with correct permission.

Now i have this playbook

```
---
- hosts: pc070
  tasks:
   - name: Find home
     find:
        paths: /home
        recurse: no
        file_type: directory
     register: homedir

   - name: Create temp directory
     file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}/temp"
        state: directory
     with_items:
        "{{ homedir.files }}"
```

But i got dir with root owner

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was simple

```
---
- hosts: pc070
  tasks:
   - name: Find home
     find:
        paths: /home
        recurse: no
        file_type: directory
     register: homedir

   - name: Create ASS directory
     file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}/bigboobsinside"
        state: directory
     with_items:
        "{{ homedir.files }}"
   - name: Set permission
     file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: directory
        recurse: yes
        owner: "{{ item.path | basename }}"
        group: "domain users"
     with_items:
        "{{ homedir.files }}"
```